# How to use a Kubernetes custom resource as a deployment config?

Tags: kubernetes, operator-sdk

I am looking for a soltion that enables the automatic update of my deployment once the config (env-variable) are updated with new data. As ConfigMaps don´t support such generic rollout, i am thinking about creating an Operator using the operator SDK that achieves this. 
The main idea would be creating a CRD and a CR instance that holds the config, use that config in deployment env-variable.. and the controller will reconcile the state of my deployment whenevr a change is happening to my CR. 
therefore i am wondering how to use the CR data in my deployment manifest?

Comment: Have you seen this project: [Github.com: Stakater: Reloader](https://github.com/stakater/Reloader)? It can watch changes in ConfigMap and Secret and do rolling upgrades on Pods with their associated DeploymentConfigs, Deployments, Daemonsets and Statefulsets.

Comment: If you're using Helm, you can [set an annotation on the Deployment to a hash of the ConfigMap content](https://helm.sh/docs/howto/charts_tips_and_tricks/#automatically-roll-deployments); when the (generated) ConfigMap changes, the (generated) annotation will change too, triggering a reload.  That'll probably be much easier than writing a custom operator.